# Tesseract loading language throws error - Swift4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, tesseract

I'm trying to convert image to text in Swift 4 language. I have followed the below link to use Tesseract library https://www.raywenderlich.com/306-tesseract-ocr-tutorial-for-ios
but i am getting error.

```
Error opening data file /var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA48E754-38FC-4DE7-AD9E-303CA3689F1C/DriverApp.app/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
2018-11-23 00:01:56.747525+0530 DriverApp[444:41494] ERROR! Can't init Tesseract engine.
```

Source Code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        imageView.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.imageToText(myImage: (info[.originalImage] as? UIImage)!)
            })

        //imageToText(myImage: imageView.image!)
    }
    func imageToText(myImage: UIImage)
    {
        if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
            // 2
            tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined
            // 3
            tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .auto
            // 4
            tesseract.image = myImage.g8_blackAndWhite()
            // 5
            tesseract.recognize()
            // 6
            ocrText.text = tesseract.recognizedText
        }
        // 7
        //activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

    }
```

I have added the tessdata wiht eng.traineddata file into xcode project.
Please anybody provide me an idea.

Comment: Can you verify that your tesseract version and tessdata version match? [Tessdata for v4.0](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) and [Tessdata for version 3.0*](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00)

Comment: Did you already try the tutorial's suggestion: "Note: Make sure tessdata is placed in the Copy Bundle Resources under Build Phases otherwise you’ll receive a cryptic error when running stating the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is not set to the parent directory of your tessdata directory."

Comment: @kezi yes, i can able to see eng.traineddata in "Copy Bundle Resources"

Comment: @DmitriiZ. how to find the version of TestData ?

Comment: You find it based on where you downloaded it from. If it came bundled with tesseract - I doubt it differs. If uou downloaded it manually - check that you did it from the correct branch.